# a physical question about probability

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

assume that we have a cubic box which contains a large number of molecules. Therefore we know that the molecules move in different directions and hit the walls of the box  . I read somewhere that with a good approximation it  is possible to say that 1/3of molecules move in the x direction,1/3to the y and 1/3to z.my question is that what would then be the probability of each walls in X,YandZ direction if we have a cuboid which would be a kind  of cube that has been stretched in the x direction for example?

Comment: The statement "$1/3$rd of the molecules move in the $x$ direction" is not strictly accurate as molecules do not actually move at right angles all the time, but it captures the intuition. The same remains true for an elongated box. However, it is also true that fewer molecules hit the farther $x$-walls of the box than the other walls, but this is simply because the other walls have a larger area.

Answer (score 0):

The statement that the molecules are moving randomly in a three-dimensional space is equivalent to saying each of them has $1/3^{rd}$ probability to move along a particular axis (or in other words, that $1/3^{rd}$ of them are moving along each of the three directions). Even if they are in a cuboid the axes remain the same - each of the molecule will still have the same chance of moving along a particular direction (and it doesn't depend on the length of the cuboid you place it in). So still you can make the approximation that $1/3^{rd}$ of them are moving along each coordinate axis. However the probability that a molecule will hit a wall may vary (it will be less for the wall parallel to $yz$-plane in this case).

Suppose we take a cuboid with lengths $1,1,t$ where $t>1$. If probability of hitting the wall parallel to the $xy$-plane is $p$, then probability of hitting the wall parallel to $xz$-plane is $p$, and that of hitting the wall parallel to $yz$-plane is $tp$

$$p+p+tp=1~~~~~\Rightarrow ~~~~~p=\frac{1}{2+p}$$

Comment: "The statement that the molecules are moving randomly in a three-dimensional space is equivalent to saying each of them has 1/3rd probability to move along a particular axis"... Sorry but absolutely not.